# In the company team web page, the footer and sidenav overlap each other

Tags: bug, design, old-teams

When the [Team page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) is scrolled down completely, the *side navigation* bar and the *footer* overlap each other, making the footer links difficult to read.